# Regex for valid MAC addresses : not 88|87|FF|00

Tags: regex, mac-address

A "valid" MAC address is 6 groups of hexadecimal character pairs, separated by a dash or colon.

Example:

```
3D-F2-C9-A6-B3-4F
08:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F
```

However, "invalid" MAC addresses contain hex pairs that are `00`, `FF`, `88` or `87`.

Example:

```
00-00-00-00-00-00
FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF
88-88-88-88-87-88
```

This is what I got so far:

```
(?!8)([0-9A-F]{2})([:-][0-9A-F]{2}){5}
```

But for some reason I don't know why, I cannot use:

```
(?!88|87|FF|00)
```

For the negated portion of the regex.

*NOTE:* Not a duplicate SO entry because this looks for invalid hex pairs and excludes them.

Comment: Do the rules specify that no single byte value can be `00`, `FF`, `88`, or `87` or that the entire string cannot be `87-87-87-87-87-87`?

Comment: No, this question has a specific additional rule for 4 byte patterns, and it's exactly that pattern which causes the problem here.

Comment: Why do you have to do it in a single regex? Validate the MAC address, and then test for invalid combinations using capture groups from that first test.

Comment: @Dai that would be the case for the zeros and F's, but not for 88 or 87, so it requires us to check each 2 chars in-between the colon or dash. hrbrmstr: that one is not a duplicate for this post, technically the invalid ones are "kosher" Mac address that aren't set correctly. KenWhite: I am trying to validate the MAC address, I don't care how the regex is written (groups or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead on the entire input:

```
^((?!00|FF|88|87)[0-9A-F]{2}([:-]|$)){6}$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/2X5bwrfrB5).

Note how your regex can be simplified by using an alternation for a separator or end of input.

Comment: Flipping awesome!!! Especially the separator or end of input that way you can repeat this group exactly the number of times that is required. You rock!!! Thank you.

Comment: @Vippy your edit changes the match, so I just want to check: Is `FF-F2-C9-A6-88-4F` "valid" (some terms "good", some "bad")?